# Unable to mark Items as shipped, nothing under previously shipped items in shipments

Tags: orders, shipping, redis

When I click on the "Ship" button on the orders page there is nothing under "Items to Ship" it's just blank but everything above that appears to load normally.
Also If I go to the shipments page all the shipments that I was able to make before this problem are in the list but if I open any of them there is no information on the page just shipment No, date sent, email sent & the three buttons on the right.
I have a feeling it might have something to do with Redis cache which I have dissabled but still the same.[image: No data under Items to ship]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your situation, it means you have problem in `sales/order/shipment/create/items.phtml` or `sales/order/shipment/create/items/renderer/default.phtml` file. This file is responsible for rendering your order items. I think it is not being called.

Check `<adminhtml_sales_order_shipment_new>` tag in `design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/sales.xml` file, you will find out about `item renderer`.

Also check if anything (extension) is overwriting this file.
I doubt it's being overridden.

Comment: I've checked the sales.xml file against a site which is still working ok & they look the same.  How can I check if an extension is overwriting it?

Comment: Yes, they look same, but the `items.phtml` file is not rendering the content, means something wrong wether in `intems.phtml` or in `default.phtml` file.

Comment: I've had a look at the two files but to be honest if there was a problem with them it would need to jump off of the screen & slap me round the face.  Is there a way of seeing if an error is being generated anywhere?